# How to use spring service interfaces and implementations in gwt by coding less?

Tags: java, spring, gwt, maven

i have a maven project having two modules; one spring module and one for gwt module. gwt module depends to spring module. And i have XService interfaces and XServiceImpl implementations as Spring beans annotated as @Service("myXServiceImpl").

I want to call myXServiceImpl bean's method from gwt client-side. For this purpose i write proper gwt classes; XGWTService, XGWTServiceAsync, XGWTServiceImpl and XGWTServiceImpl uses XService by @Autowired (I use spring4gwt and XGWTServiceImpl is a spring bean annotated as @Service("myXGWTServiceImpl"))

Actually, i want a practical solution as simple as defining only XGWTServiceAsync which is annotated with @RemoteServiceRelativePath("spring4gwt/myXServiceImpl")

I wonder if there is an easy way to call my spring beans without coding extra 3 classes(XGWTService, XGWTServiceAsync, XGWTServiceImpl)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Put the XService interface and all the classes used by it in a separate package. Make the XService extend RemoteService.  You can then define a GWT module that includes those classes. Package the source along with the jar file. Inherit the GWT module in your main GWT module and implement only the XServiceAsync interface.

You can also do away with manually implementing the XServiceAsync - the maven GWT plugin has an option to generate the Async version from the interface.

The only awkward thing in this is making the XService implement the RemoteService interface of GWT and thus having to make your service implementation depend on the GWT jar.  But since it doesn't come in the way of implementation that is something that we can live with.

The other option is to just create a XGwtService interface that extends XService & RemoteService - not add any additional methods into this.  On the server just the XServiceImpl should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the answer gkamal but i think those advices don't bring an easier solution because interfaces and spring beans impementing my interfaces don't need to depend on gwt modules. Actually, i want a practical solution as simple as defining only XGWTServiceAsync which is annotated with @RemoteServiceRelativePath("spring4gwt/myXServiceImpl").